# Why use `express.static` instead of just `response.sendFile`?

Tags: node.js, express

Simple question. In an Express app, when looking to serve files under a certain root directory, theres the `express.static` middleware like so:

```js
app.use(base, express.static(root));
```

But it looks like the same thing can be done by just using `response.sendFile` like so:

```js
app.use(base, (req, res) => res.sendFile(req.path, { root: root }));
```

What the advantage of one over the other, and when would I use each?

Answer (score 1):

[`res.sendFile`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L31) uses [send](https://www.npmjs.com/package/send) package underly.

> `Send` is a library for streaming files from the file system as a http response supporting partial responses (Ranges), conditional-GET negotiation (If-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Modified-Since), high test coverage, and granular events which may be leveraged to take appropriate actions in your application or framework.

Some files like user files may require the program to perform some logic to determine whether to send and the path of the file. So, it provides fine-grained support for serving files.

But for pure static files such as HTML, JS, CSS, we do not need fine-grain control, so we can use `express.static`

[`express.static`](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L81) is [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static), it serve up entire folders mapped to URLs.

Comment: This still doesn't really answer why I wouldn't just use `app.use(base, (req, res) => res.sendFile(req.path, { root: root }));` to serve static files though. It does the same thing as `express.static` far as I can tell.

Comment: Also, looking at the source for `serve-static` on GitHub confirms that it also uses `send` internally, so I'm still not sure why I'd ever use it over the one-liner.

Comment: hi @AaronBeaudoin - it's absolutely, totally, completely normal in programming that we wrap a function in a clear simplification.  `.static` defines a certain behavior.  as you mention, it may happen to use something under the hood currently: that could change or otherwise in the future.  for any call in any programming milieu, it's always possible, as you suggest, to "not use it and do it yourself" if you feel like it. note that indeed many programmers (or in specific situations) just don't like using `express` and trivially do things by hand instead.